# Inner Join Many to Many Tables with Filter In MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

table structure ....Here is only 3 tables.. (bought ,customer,product). ..

```
bought table structure : fields (id,product_id,customer_id), 
customer table structure: (customer_id,name,address) , 
product table structure: (product_id,name).
```

inside the product table included product a and b. From the bought table i want to get customer id (customers who bought product 'a' but did not buy products 'b').

Using mysql or similar, how would you select all customers who bought product 'a' but did not buy products 'b', Without using subselects. (make sure there are no customers bought product 'b' in the result.) ..please help me

Comment: You just edit your previous question..........But you don't say what you have tried ??

Comment: You have said in your question that "there are no customers bought product 'b' in the result", What does that mean? If I am understanding correctly that there are no customers who bought product 'b', then what you want is only customers who bought product 'a'. this can simply be done using select query...

Comment: It may not be done using a simple SELECT query because there are 3 tables involved. So, it needs to be joined. If you can't solve filtering by MySQL, solve it with PHP by filtering the data.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure, you want to filter by product name? Maybe i'm missing something in your question, but i think this should work

```
select customer_id 
from
bought b
inner join customer c on b.customer_id = b.customer_id
inner join product p on p.product_id = b.product_id
where p.name = 'a'
```

Comment: current query showing one common product named as 1 ..but only shows product a.....

Comment: how can this be happening? the where claues is '=', products named '1' will not show

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get customers who bought product 'a' but did not buy
>   products 'b'

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN
(
     SELECT * 
     FROM bought 
     WHERE product_id = id of 'a'
) ba ON c.CustomerId = ba.CustomerId
LEFT JOIN
(
     SELECT * 
     FROM bought 
     WHERE product_id = id of 'b'
) bb ON c.CustomerId = bb.CustomerId
WHERE bb.CustomerId IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for all..i want query with out using subquery ,.. now i got the answer ..""  select b.customer_id from bought b inner join customer c on c.customer_id = b.customer_id inner join product p on p.product_id = b.product_id where p.name = 'a' and b.customer_id NOT IN (p.name = 'a') "" ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the whole set of answers to your table and joins.

**Customer**

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  customer_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(50),
  address varchar(100)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Product**

```
CREATE TABLE product (
  product_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(50)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Bought or Transactions**

```
CREATE TABLE bought (
  id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  product_id int,
  customer_id int,
  FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product(product_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer(customer_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**INSERT values**

```
INSERT INTO customer (name, address) VALUEs ("George","Kentucky")
INSERT INTO customer (name, address) VALUEs ("Stan","Dublin")
INSERT INTO customer (name, address) VALUEs ("Kazaam","UAE")
INSERT INTO customer (name, address) VALUEs ("Sarah","New York")

INSERT INTO product (name) VALUES ("tomato")
INSERT INTO product (name) VALUES ("apple")

INSERT INTO bought (customer_id, product_id) VALUEs("1","2")
INSERT INTO bought (customer_id, product_id) VALUEs("2","1")
INSERT INTO bought (customer_id, product_id) VALUEs("3","1")
INSERT INTO bought (customer_id, product_id) VALUEs("4","1")
```

**Inner Join with Filter**  --> this will be your $query

```
SELECT customer.customer_id, customer.name as customer_name, product.name as product_name
FROM customer
INNER JOIN bought ON customer.customer_id = bought.customer_id
INNER JOIN product ON product.product_id = bought.product_id 
WHERE product.name LIKE "apple" AND product.name NOT LIKE "tomato"
ORDER BY customer.name
```

This will filter all the customers who bought apples. All you have to do is just change the **product.name** value. If you want to change the fields, change the first line of the **INNER JOIN**.

**Explanation of Venn Diagram:**
If you are going to think about it, MySQL is following the design of Venn Diagram. It cannot intersect 3 objects and filter them. You are trying to go beyond what the design of Venn Diagram by means of constructing another circle in the middle. See figure below.

[image]

So, to solve your problem on PHP, we create that inner circle. You run a loop for getting all the customer_id(s) that has "apples" on the product_name. Then do a loop of mysql_fetch array again. and output only the customer_ids with "apples."

If you can't solve filtering by MySQL, solve it with PHP by filtering the data.